# How to add data file to PostgreSQL database tablespace?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I am using PostgreSQL and I want to add a new data files to existing tablespace  ( like in [oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/dfiles002.htm#ADMIN11422) )

I could not found any description on this on PostgreSQL documentation. 
How to do this ?

Comment: What is a "data file" in this context? This doesn't make a ton of sense. What are you trying to accomplish? What's the underlying problem you are attempting to solve?

Comment: when current tablespace is not enough ( in size ) how we can extend the size of tablespace while table is is been used by application ( may be by transactions) ?

Comment: This is why it helps if you explain what you intend to do, and why. Don't just say "how do I do X from Oracle in PostgreSQL" - try to explain what X is and why you want it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PotgreSQL works different than Oracle. It has a much simpler concept for data storage. Data blocks, extents and segments don't exist. In the same spirit, a tablespace is not split into multiple data files. You just create the tablespace and PostgreSQL creates the necessary files to store the data.

When creating a tablespace, you can provide a location, where PostgreSQL should store the data:

```
CREATE TABLESPACE dbspace LOCATION '/data/dbs';
```

This works similar to  [bigfile tablespaces](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tspaces002.htm#ADMIN01102) in Oracle, where you also don't have to manage data files.

Comment: But how can I extend the tablespace space beyond the current disk capacity? Oracle works that way so you can add infinite amount of new disks.